# SQL select count case comparing 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm breaking my head over a SQL statement comparing 2 columns and when they are not similar the statement should add 1 to the count.

Here is my code.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) CASE WHEN Column1 = Column2 THEN '0' ELSE '1' END AS result 
FROM [Sheet1$] 
GROUP BY Column1
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the error message of a missing operator in the query expression.

Comment: Remove double quote in the end of your SQL

Comment: @YoriKusanagi It doesn't even get to that point, there's already a syntax error earlier :)

Comment: @hvd gotcha, missing a comma "COUNT(*), CASE..."

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT(*)` is going to count the rows regardless of the value in result.

`SUM(result)` might be what you are looking for

Comment: SELECT SUM(result) CASE WHEN SrceTgtQty = Srce.a.qty THEN result+0 ELSE result+1 END AS result FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY SrceTgtQty"

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Column1 = Column2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS NumberOfDiffs,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Column1 = Column2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfEquals
FROM [Sheet1$]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*)
WHERE NOT (Column1 = Column2)
FROM [Sheet1$]
```

will count how many rows don't have equal columns.

Comment: No, this will count how many rows have unequal columns. If any value is `NULL`, "don't have equal columns" (actually more like "can't be shown to have equal columns") and "have unequal columns" evaluate differently.

Comment: Treatment of Nulls is a valid concern, but I don't see anything in the Question that suggests how Nulls (if any) should be counted.

Comment: The question's approach (`CASE WHEN a = b THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`) would count them: `a = b` cannot be shown to be TRUE, so the `ELSE` expression is taken. But you may be right that the OP didn't really think about it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. But whatever I try it keeps giving the error about a missing operator.

Comment: Start with something that works, e.g. just do a count(*) on the table.  Your syntax above has errors, so it's a poor starting point.  You have a `COUNT(*)` next to `CASE`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll start off again and now very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count the number of absent days from a attendance table use the following query, D1 is the first day, D2 is the second day...and so on

```
SELECT     TOP (200) PayrollYear, PayrollMonth, EmployeeId, EmployeeName, JobNo, SUM(CASE WHEN D1 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D2 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D3 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D4 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D5 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D6 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D7 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D8 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D9 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D10 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D11 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D12 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D13 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D14 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D15 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D16 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D17 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D18 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D19 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D20 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D21 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D22 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D23 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D24 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D25 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D26 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D27 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D28 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      + SUM(CASE WHEN D29 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D30 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN D31 = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                      AS TotAbsent
FROM         T_EmpAttendance
GROUP BY PayrollYear, PayrollMonth, EmployeeId, EmployeeName, JobNo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*),CASE WHEN col1=col2 THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END AS x
FROM theTable
group by CASE WHEN col1=col2 THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END
```

I am using Oracle, it do not allow me to group by x (alias name) so I am grouping by CASE statement and it works fine.